# How to slide (push) child views inside layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

I'm planning to construct UI with sliding child views inside layout.

```
+--------------+     +--------------+     +--------------+
|    view1     |     |    view1     |     |    view1     |
+--------------+     +--------------+     +--------------+
|              |     +--------------+     |    view2     |
|    view3     | <=> |              | <=> +--------------+
|              |     |    view3     |     |              |
|              |     |              |     |    view3     |
|              |     |              |     |              |
+--------------+     +--------------+     +--------------+
```

F.e. view2 must slide with animation from behind view1 pushing view3 down.

Is it possible to implement this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it possible. Just use [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html).

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view2, "height", 0, 100);
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.start();
```

Keep in mind that you can use it with API level 11 and up.

**But** if you need it for all version of the platform back to 1.0 use [NineOldAndroids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids) library.